# Can pixi.js and three.js be used together?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, pixi.js

Is it possible to make 2D graphics with pixi.js, then add 3D objects with three.js or rotate 2D pixi objects in the same view?

For example, can a 2D gui be made with pixi, then rotated into the scene in 3D with three.js?

Or is it impossible to use the two libraries like this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to glue them together, but it depends on what you need to do with it (how will your 2D GUI work)?

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried the twitter interface on Android lately? It's a 2D interface, but when you go to a new view/screen, there's a slight 3D zoom animation. Subtle things like that are what I'm imagining. Do you think that could work? Could you briefly describe how the two could be glued together (describe a small use case)?

Comment: this sounds like a need that would be much better filled by using CSS animations/translations

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can and it is super easy. If you have a lot of custom shapes, text or complex rendering, this will easily outperform doing the same in regular html, css and javascript.

Three JS can consume a Pixi JS render by doing the following:

```
// globals
var pixiCanvas, pixiRenderer, threeJsPixiTexture;

// one time setup
const width = 8192; // change to your desired value
const height = 4096; // change to your desired value
pixiCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
pixiCanvas.width = width;
pixiCanvas.height = height;
pixiRenderer = new PIXI.Renderer({ view: pixiCanvas, width: width, height: height, antialias: false, autoResize: false, resolution: 1.0, transparent: true });
threeJsPixiTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(pixiRenderer.view);

// render logic (in animate method most likely)

// Render stuff with pixiRenderer...
// draw rects, text, a container, whatever you want

// make sure texture updates
threeJsPixiTexture.needsUpdate = true;

// you can assign threeJsPixiTexture to the map on a material, render it as full screen quad, etc.
```

Comment: Thanks jixtra! That is indeed a good way to mix them. I'm also wondering if it is possible to mix them in the same 3D space in a single canvas, but it doesn't seem feasible. One way could be to have a separate canvas per Pixi shape, but that might get expensive.

Comment: I am not sure if sharing the same canvas is possible. I suppose you could pass the same canvas to both pixi and three js renderers and see what happens :) for me I want the pixi js texture in a separate material, not full screen so I need the separate canvas, but if you just want pixi as a full screen overlay, you could try running on the same canvas.

Comment: but how do I use the app.stage in this context? or how can I add my pixi.sprite(); to the canvas without the app.stage instance?

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll need two different canvases.
One possibility would be render the pixi's canvas to a texture and map it onto a 3d shape (in three.js canvas) but it looks neither easy nor useful.
I would rather suggest you to use CCS3 transformations in order to apply 3D transforms to your pixi's canvas.

May I ask you what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Late response, but I wanted to put pixi objects in the same 3D space as Three.js objects. One way could be to render individual Pixi objects to separate canvases, and make a THREE.CanvasTexture from them, but that would be expensive.